# PrimeNG data table conditional cell formatting

Tags: css, angular, datatable, primeng

I am trying to color the content of individual cell based on value of that cell.
for example if the cell value(numeric) is negative then it should display cell value(numeric) in red color.

Here is what I have tried:

```
<p-dataTable #dt [value]="DataList" [rows]="10" [paginator]="true" [pageLinks]="4" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10,20,50,100]" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="400px">
<p-column [style]="{'width':'134px','text-align':'right'}" field="UnitChange" header="Units Change" [sortable]="true"> </p-column>
<p-column [style]="{'width':'134px','text-align':'right'}" field="UnitPercentChange" header="% Change (Units)" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
```

Comment: PrimeNG != PrimeFaces!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeng 2.0-RC.1 released and it has some changes and enhancements about cell editing maybe upgrading your version will help.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I achieved it by manipulating the DOM using JQuery after PrimeNG has applied the css classes.

Comment: Could you post your solution? I'm trying to do the same thing and I'm running into all sorts of issues.

Answer (score 3):

@AnandCMS,

You do not have to use jQuery to achieve this. This can be done by minor tweaks in the PrimeNG template itself.

Make use of `<template>` within `<p-column>` and bind class *.error* to it when data is negative value.

Updated template:

```
<p-column [style]="{'width':'134px','text-align':'right'}" field="UnitChange" header="Units Change" [sortable]="true">
   <template let-col let-data="rowData" pTemplate="body">
      <span [ngClass]="{'error': (data[col.field] < 0) }">{{ data[col.field] }}</span>
   </template>
</p-column>
```

Now in your css:

```
.error {
  color: red;
}
```

Please try this and update.

Comment: This would apply the style to whole row.The question was to apply to a cell.